# RouterOS - creating user only with access to tools

Tags: router, radius, accounting

I have 3 different networks and I'd like users from network A to be able to wake up pc network B (ofc with certain password) so I guess it could be good idea to allow them to use WOL capabilities built in router.

Comment: how about setting up a raspberry pi for this task, that one could as well log SNMP data from the router and print nice graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Webfig](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Webfig) to create an interface for a certain user where he can  only access certain areas of the router management (tools in your scenario).